# What is the pattern?

Tags: math, sequence

I have a list of keys with some corresponding hex values.
The first 3 digits are the key and the rest is the value:

```
Key Value
110 02 30 30 81 56 8B 80 F4 4F 03
111 02 30 30 81 56 8B 81 F5 4F 03
112 02 30 30 81 56 8B 82 F6 4F 03
113 02 30 30 81 56 8B 83 F7 4F 03
114 02 30 30 81 56 8B 84 F8 4F 03
115 02 30 30 81 56 8B 85 F9 4F 03
116 02 30 30 81 56 8B 86 FA 4F 03
117 02 30 30 81 56 8B 87 FB 4F 03
118 02 30 30 81 56 8B 88 FC 4F 03
119 02 30 30 81 56 8B 89 FD 4F 03
120 02 30 30 81 56 8C 80 F5 4F 03
121 02 30 30 81 56 8C 81 F6 4F 03
122 02 30 30 81 56 8C 82 F7 4F 03
123 02 30 30 81 56 8C 83 F8 4F 03
124 02 30 30 81 56 8C 84 F9 4F 03
125 02 30 30 81 56 8C 85 FA 4F 03
126 02 30 30 81 56 8C 86 FB 4F 03
127 02 30 30 81 56 8C 87 FC 4F 03
128 02 30 30 81 56 8C 88 FD 4F 03
129 02 30 30 81 56 8C 89 FE 4F 03
130 02 30 30 81 56 8D 80 F6 4F 03
131 02 30 30 81 56 8D 81 F7 4F 03
132 02 30 30 81 56 8D 82 F8 4F 03
133 02 30 30 81 56 8D 83 F9 4F 03
134 02 30 30 81 56 8D 84 FA 4F 03
135 02 30 30 81 56 8D 85 FB 4F 03
136 02 30 30 81 56 8D 86 FC 4F 03
137 02 30 30 81 56 8D 87 FD 4F 03
138 02 30 30 81 56 8D 88 FE 4F 03
139 02 30 30 81 56 8D 89 FF 4F 03
140 02 30 30 81 56 8E 80 F7 4F 03
141 02 30 30 81 56 8E 81 F8 4F 03
142 02 30 30 81 56 8E 82 F9 4F 03
143 02 30 30 81 56 8E 83 FA 4F 03
144 02 30 30 81 56 8E 84 FB 4F 03
145 02 30 30 81 56 8E 85 FC 4F 03
146 02 30 30 81 56 8E 86 FD 4F 03
147 02 30 30 81 56 8E 87 FE 4F 03
148 02 30 30 81 56 8E 88 FF 4F 03
149 02 30 30 81 56 8E 89 F0 5F 03
150 02 30 30 81 56 8F 80 F8 4F 03
151 02 30 30 81 56 8F 81 F9 4F 03
152 02 30 30 81 56 8F 82 FA 4F 03
153 02 30 30 81 56 8F 83 FB 4F 03
154 02 30 30 81 56 8F 84 FC 4F 03
155 02 30 30 81 56 8F 85 FD 4F 03
156 02 30 30 81 56 8F 86 FE 4F 03
157 02 30 30 81 56 8F 87 FF 4F 03
158 02 30 30 81 56 8F 88 F0 5F 03
159 02 30 30 81 56 8F 89 F1 5F 03
160 02 30 30 81 56 90 80 F9 4F 03
161 02 30 30 81 56 90 81 FA 4F 03
162 02 30 30 81 56 90 82 FB 4F 03
163 02 30 30 81 56 90 83 FC 4F 03
164 02 30 30 81 56 90 84 FD 4F 03
165 02 30 30 81 56 90 85 FE 4F 03
166 02 30 30 81 56 90 86 FF 4F 03
167 02 30 30 81 56 90 87 F0 5F 03
168 02 30 30 81 56 90 88 F1 5F 03
169 02 30 30 81 56 90 89 F2 5F 03
170 02 30 30 81 56 91 80 FA 4F 03
171 02 30 30 81 56 91 81 FB 4F 03
172 02 30 30 81 56 91 82 FC 4F 03
173 02 30 30 81 56 91 83 FD 4F 03
174 02 30 30 81 56 91 84 FE 4F 03
175 02 30 30 81 56 91 85 FF 4F 03
176 02 30 30 81 56 91 86 F0 5F 03
177 02 30 30 81 56 91 87 F1 5F 03
178 02 30 30 81 56 91 88 F2 5F 03
179 02 30 30 81 56 91 89 F3 5F 03
180 02 30 30 81 56 92 80 FB 4F 03
181 02 30 30 81 56 92 81 FC 4F 03
182 02 30 30 81 56 92 82 FD 4F 03
183 02 30 30 81 56 92 83 FE 4F 03
184 02 30 30 81 56 92 84 FF 4F 03
185 02 30 30 81 56 92 85 F0 5F 03
186 02 30 30 81 56 92 86 F1 5F 03
187 02 30 30 81 56 92 87 F2 5F 03
188 02 30 30 81 56 92 88 F3 5F 03
189 02 30 30 81 56 92 89 F4 5F 03
```

I can't work out the relationship between the 2 numbers.

- Bits 11 and 12 seem to relate to the tens in the key and are sequential
- Bits 13 - 19 seem to be related to the units in the key but are not sequential (not in hex, decimal or binary)

The system was created in Spain (not sure if that matters)

Is this number sequential? Is there a pattern? i.e. can a program be written to calculate the Nth key's value?

Comment: Why don't you convert the value to decimal and see if the pattern is clearer?  I don't think as well in hex; I'm guessing you don't, either.

Comment: That's what I've been doing: At record/key 139 to 140 the value jumps from 8D 89 FF 4F to 8E 80 F7 4F I can't work out how or why. Also the sequence counts on 2 bytes (112 = 82 F6 and 113 = 83 F7) I was wondering if anyone knew why so I could write a program to calculate the nth value rather than having to build a look up table

Comment: You'd have to know how hex numbers work: 0-9 A-F.   Should be addition.

Comment: Take the Key 112 -- 82 F6 for example, I don't know if it's 2 decimal numbers (130)(246) or simply (33,526) if it's 2 decimal numbers, then the sequence goes up in 1s until Key 140 (then there's a jump I don't understand) if it's 1 number then I can't even see a pattern

Comment: Can someone please explain why I'm getting down voted? I tried to find a pattern by converting different parts of the value to decimal, I know someone more clever than me can do this I'll fix the question given a little advice. Thank you

Comment: @Smithy probably because your question has little to do with programming or with [the kind of questions that are expected on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You're asking people to spend their time solving some kind of _numeric riddle_ which presents **zero** interest or usefulness for anybody but you, as would an eventual answer if it were ever provided. It might be fun as a mental exercise but there are definitely better SE sites for asking this.

Comment: @walen That's a fair comment mate, I was just confused as to why it was getting closed for being "unclear what I'm asking", got my answer though so whoop! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `data[i, j]` represent the value in row `i`, column `j`, where `i` and `j` are both at least `1`:

- `data[i + 1, 1] = data[i, 1] + 1`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 2] = 02`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 3] = 30`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 4] = 81`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 5] = 56`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 6] = 8B + ((i - 1) - (i - 1) % A) / A`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 7] = 80 + ((i - 1) % A)`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 8] = F0 + (4 + ((i - 1) - (i - 1) % A) / A + i) % 10`
- for all `i`, `data[i, 9] = 4F + 10 * ((4 + ((i - 1) - (i - 1) % A) / A + i) - ((4 + ((i - 1) - (i - 1) % A) / A + i) % 10) / 10)`
- for all `i`, `data[i, A] = 03`

Note that columns 6 and 7 represent a number equal to `8B7F + i`. Also, column 9 represents whether the counter in column 8 has "wrapped around" `F` and started back at `0`. In that sense, the 4 low-order bits of column 9 and column 8 can be taken as a three-digit number whose value is a "rolling window" with increment `1` and period `A`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough mate, I really appreciate it. I'm going to try and get this coded up and put later :)